# Stuck in a JavaScript stack algorithm

Tags: javascript, stack

The isEmpty() algorithm is asking me to return true when the stack contains no values and to return false when stack contains one or more values. it also asks to complete this without modifying the stack

i can only use 3 methods

- .pop() which pops the top value of the stack
- .push() which pushes a value on to the stack
- .peek() which shows me the top value of the stack without modifying the stack

i tried doing the algorithm this way but it only completed the last two requirements which where to return false when the stack contains one or more values and to not modify the stack but it wont return true when the stack contains no values [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8ht.png)

```
function isEmpty(stack) {
if(stack!==''){
  return false
}else if(stack===''){
  return true
}
}
```

Comment: perhaps when "the stack" is empty, it doesn't have the value `''` (i.e. an empty string) - but since we can't see what *possible* values `stack` can be, then it's hard to help

Answer (score 1):

```
function isEmpty(stack) {
  if (stack.peek() === undefined) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

OR

```
function isEmpty(stack) {
  return stack.peek() === undefined;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way you could use the peek() method to solve this problem:

```
function isEmpty(stack) {
if(stack.peek() === undefined){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use the pop() method, but you will have to add the values again to the stack:

```
function isEmpty(stack) {
var temp = stack.pop();
if(temp === undefined){
    return true;
}else{
    stack.push(temp);
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

just check if the `peek()` function is equalto undefined

```
function isEmpty(){
return peek() == undefined;
}
```